# How to rotate 3D AR object 360 degree using touch with vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hi I am working with vuforia sdk in Unity..I have an AR Object.How to rotate the object 360 Degrees(rotate all sides) by touch? .So far i can rotate it left and right using following code..

Thanks!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour {
    public Bounds bounds;
    public float speed = 1.0F;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        if (collider == null) {
            collider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
            Debug.Log("No Collider is Detected");
        }
        bounds = collider.bounds;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            if(bounds.size.magnitude > 0){
                var dtx = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*speed;
                var dty = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*speed;
                var pivot = bounds.center;

                transform.RotateAround(pivot,Vector3.up,dtx);
                transform.RotateAround(pivot,Vector3.left,dty);
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very[100%] Possible .....Rotate, Scale, Translate all are possible

Comment: Do you know  C# script snippet? @RasaMohamed

Comment: You are asking Answer Directly, without trying and research, I'll try to give

Comment: Stack Overflow generally isn't a site where users write up a solution from scratch for you. Please demonstrate that you've done some research, and at least attempted to solve the problem yourself - if you continue to face problems after that, post your own code here and we'd be happy to help debug/improve it.

Comment: this is my code for rotation ..but i can rotate only left and right..